# An unhandled exception of type system.net.webException occured in microsoft.sharepoint.client.dll

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-online, csom

[click here to see the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTBt1.png)

I am using visual studio 2015......I need to connect to sharepoint through visual stuido.

I added microsoft sharepoint online csom reference in vs 2015

but i unable to execute the code due to error.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint Online, please use SharePointOnlineCredentials class to set credentials to ClientContext object, here is a code snippet for your reference:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace CSOMWinApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string password = "xxxxxx";
            string account = "user@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
            var secret = new System.Security.SecureString();
            foreach (char c in password)
            {
                secret.AppendChar(c);
            }

            var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://zheguo.sharepoint.com/sites/dev"))
            {

                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
                Web web = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:

[SharePoint Online console application with csom](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/csom-sharepoint-online-console-application/)